# Created jquery rows but nothing displays nor does the on('hover') method work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an Etch A Sketch for a programming project. The default button adds rows, however nothing appears on my screen, but the dev tools show the rows as being created. I've tried changing the margin,padding,etc still nothing. Also, the button's second set of events is never triggered properly, it will just highlight all the rows black instead of allowing me to change them as i hover over them.
https://lettda.github.io/EtchAsketch/

**UPDATE: Display has been resolved ('.' in front of newRow in html removed), fixing the hover event is the only problem**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      var i;

  function gridCreate (){
      $('.grid').empty();

      var userNum = prompt("How big do you want your grid?");

      for (var i = 0; i < userNum; i++) { 
          $('.grid').append("<div class = 'newRow'></div>");
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
          $('.newRow').append("<div class='square'></div>");
      }

      var newWidth = $('.square').width() * i;
      $('.newRow').width(newWidth);
      $('.grid').width($('.newRow').width());

      var newHeight = $('.square').height() * i;
      // $('.newRow').height(newHeight);
      $('.grid').height($('.newRow').height());
  };


   $('.normal').on("click", function(){
          gridCreate();
      // $('.square').unbind();
  $('.square').on("hover", function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
      });
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.newRow {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.square {
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
    text-align: center;
    float: none !important;
}
.navButtons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Try Inspecting the elements to see whats going on -- if you dont know how to Inspect elements using the Dev tools of a browser -- google "how to inspect elements" -- check the console for Errors -- you have double dots in some of your code. you only need one

Comment: Oh, and you want `.newRow`, not `..newRow`

Comment: Oh, and `class="newRow"`, but ... damnit, I'll just post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a few issues here.

1. ClassNames can't start with '.' ([See W3 CSS Grammar Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)). Set `class='myClassName'` without any dots and perform a jQuery lookup with only one '.'.
2. There are no margins in your CSS, so `squares` will appear to be one wide row. See below for a potential CSS solution.
3. In this case, multiplying `i` for generating dimensions doesn't break anything, but code shouldn't rely on quirky issues in JS, I'd suggest being more explicit and referencing the `userNum` variable already defined in scope.
4. Listener events can only be added to DOM elements after they've been appended to the DOM not before, so async-wise that listener never triggers. You need to add the listeners after the `squares` were added.
5. `hover` isn't a real event type. You'd want to use jQuery's [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Here's some alternative JS I'd suggest.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function gridCreate (){
    $('.grid').empty();

    var userNum = prompt("How big do you want your gid?");

    for (var i = 0; i < userNum; i++) { 
      $('.grid').append("<div class ='newRow'></div>");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
      $('.newRow').append("<div class='square'></div>");
    }

    var newWidth = ($('.square').width()+10) * userNum;
    $('.newRow').width(newWidth);
    $('.grid').width($('.newRow').width());

    var newHeight = $('.square').height() * userNum;
    $('.grid').height($('.newRow').height());

    $('.square').hover(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
  };
  $('.normal').on("click", function(){
      gridCreate();
  });
});
```

To resolve the `square` spacing issue, you'd also need to add some margins to them so they don't look like one long black bar.

```
.square { margin:0 5px;}
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lcznb8y/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice that. Even with that though the rows still get created but I all see is a line

Comment: No worries @DavidLett, when you look at code enough sometimes details in plain-sight become hard to catch.

Comment: An additional issue I noticed was with your css. You'll notice the "bars" are actually two blocks right next to each other. You can see so in the inspector tool.

Comment: @DavidLett I just posted a working demo (https://jsfiddle.net/2Lcznb8y/). Let me know how it goes, and please upvote/accept my answer if it works out. :)

Comment: You sir are the man! Thanks a lot for the help. One question why the + 10 instead of * i?

Comment: The +10 is because each square has 10px of horizontal margins in my example (5 left, 5 right). If you're OK with the squares touching each other you can remove the margin and +10